# Palindrome Program in java

Tags: java

Palindrome Program in java

Hello, I have created a java program that is intended for outputting palindrome numbers whenever it prompts the end user to enter 2 numbers from a starting endpoint to a ending endpoint. I have created this program using the BlueJ IDE whenever I compile this program there are no errors and when I go to the main window and right click on the program and go to the main method it simply doesn't run.

My question is have I missed out something for the program to not work? Any advice is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class NiceAndSquareNumbers{
    public static void main (String[]args){
    int n=0;
    long num[]=new long[100000000];

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        num[i]=0;
    }

    for(long i=1;i<=100000000;i++){
        if(isPalindrome(i)&&isPalindrome(i*i)){
            num[n++]=i*i;
        }
    }

    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    long l=scanner.nextLong();

    for(long i=0;i<l;i++){
       long a=scanner.nextLong();
       long b=scanner.nextLong();
       long count=0;

       for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
        if(num[j]!=0 & num[j]>=a && num[j]<=b){
            count++;
        }
       }
       System.out.println("Case #"+(i+1)+": "+count);
    }
}

private static boolean isPalindrome(long num){
    long n=num;
    long reverse=0;
    while(num>0){
        long digit=num%10;
        reverse=reverse*10+digit;
        num=num/10;
    }
    return(n==reverse);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you type anything into the console after running it? Your code asks for input 3 times with `scanner.nextLong();`.

Comment: No I didn't anything into the console because I'm using bluej when I manually open the console it's blank.

Comment: Well, you ask for input before you ever print anything so it _should_ be blank. You need to enter 3 numbers before you ever get to the first printing.

Comment: Ah didn't see that thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug(or unreasonable) of BlueJ, you have to print something at first then you can see the console. Add:

```
System.out.println("Welcome");
```

at the beginning of the main method. Look like this

```
public static void main (String[]args){
    System.out.println("Welcome");
    int n=0;
    //...other code
}
```

the you can see the console and you can input numbers to run your program:

[image]